# Eclipse project explorer shows org.eclipse.* files

Tags: eclipse

My Eclipse(Neon) IDE shows org.eclipse.* files. I tried to remove the files types from filters. But, it's not working.Here is the image of the project explorer : 
[Eclipse neon project explorer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaUHP.png).

Comment: What steps got you here?

Comment: @nitind Enabled maven options Download Article Sources and Download Artifact JavaDoc. Then i restarted the IDE, and rebuilt the index.

Comment: ALL of the steps, including which Neon dowload you started from (there's more than one).